# Create grails domains from ER-diagram

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I have the ER diagram. I try describe it like grails domains, but after start project just part of tables exist(created). I can't find in which place I made a mistakes.

I use MySQL database, after start only song_tag table crated

[ERD http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img661/4805/ke6jBx.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img661/4805/ke6jBx.png)

My grails domains

```
class Song {

    static hasMany = [audios: Audio, tags: Tag]

    BigInteger id

    String title
    String chorus
    Boolean chorusRepeat
    Date created
    Date updated

    static constraints = {
        tags joinTable:[name:'song_tag', key:'song_id']
    }
}


class Tag {

    static belongsTo =  Song
    static hasMany = [songs: Song]

    BigInteger id
    String name

    static constraints = {
        songs joinTable:[name: 'song_tag', key: 'tag_id']
    }
}

class Couplet {

    static belongsTo = Song

    BigInteger id
    String text
    Song song

    static constraints = {
    }
}

class Audio {

    static belongsTo = Song

    BigInteger id

    String audio
    String type
    Date created
    Date updated
    Song song

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Console  output

> 2015-02-01 14:20:36,007 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table couplet
>   (id decimal(19,2) not null auto_increment, version bigint not null,
>   song_id decimal(19,2) not null, text varchar(255) not null, primary
>   key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB Error | 2015-02-01 14:20:36,007
>   [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Incorrect column
>   specifier for column 'id'

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things which has to be changed

1)

```
 static constraints = {
    songs joinTable:[name: 'song_tag', key: 'tag_id']
}
```

it should be in mapping closure and not in constraints closure

```
static mapping = {  songs joinTable:[name: 'song_tag', key: 'tag_id']}
```

2) just remove id field from domain, it will automatically created by Gorm.